# Programming in Objective C. Kochan 3rd Chapter 4 Exercise 6

Tags: objective-c

Exercise:

"Complex numbers are numbers that contain two components: a real part and an
imaginary part. If a is the real component and b is the imaginary component, this
notation is used to represent the number:
a + b i
Write an Objective-C program that defines a new class called Complex. Following
the paradigm established for the Fraction class, define the following methods for
your new class:

```
-(void) setReal: (double) a;
-(void) setImaginary: (double) b;
-(void) print; // display as a + bi
-(double) real;
-(double) imaginary;
```

Write a test program to test your new class and methods."

Here is my solution that doesn't work:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@iterface Complex:NSObject
{
    double a, b;
}

-(void)setReal: (double) a;
-(void)setImaginary: (double) b;
-(void) print;
-(double) real;
-(double) imaginary;

@end

@implementation Complex
-(void)setReal
{
    scanf(@"Set real value %f",&a);
}
-(void)setImaginary
{
    scanf(@"Set imaginary value %f", &b);
}
-(void) print
{
    Nslog(@"Your number is %f",a+bi);
}
-(double)real
{
    Nslog(@"Real number is %f",a);
}
-(double)imaginary
{
    NSlog(@"Imaginary number is %f",b)
}

@end



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    Complex*num=[[complex alloc] init];
    [num setReal:3];
    [num setImaginary:4];
    Nslog(@"The complex number is %i",[num print]);
    [num release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Please, what is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_numbers
And also Kochan has a dedicated website regarding every single question in the book that people have: http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer Kochan's forum was my first stop. Unfortunately there is no answers there, just discussions. So you can't really check your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few obvious flaws that I can see. First, (and this may be a copy/paste error), you misspelled `interface` as `iterface`.

Second, your `print` method does not write to the NSLog correctly. You're trying to force an expression `a+bi` as the result to the format specifier `%f`. Instead, you'll want to have two arguments, with both `a` and `b` being passed separately to the NSLog call. Thus you'd have:

```
    NSLog(@"Your number is %f + %fi", a, b);
```

Lastly, your methods `real` and `imaginary` are supposed to be 'getters' for your instance variables, not functions that print to NSLog. Thus, you'll instead just want the function bodies to be `return a;` and `return b;` respectively. For the former (in full):

```
    -(double)real
    {
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help! It was my mistake with misspelled "interface". Also with "NSlog"- so obvious (once i see it :) But i have a question: How should i see from the exercise that "real" and " imaginary" - should be getters?

Comment: From your problem statement, "Following the paradigm established for the Fraction class..." I assumed that the 'Fraction class' implemented methods called `numerator` and `denominator` that returned its numerator and denominator, respectively, rather than writing them to NSLog. Do you have access to the 'Fraction class' example?

Comment: In fact, setters and getters are the basis for all class variables that are meant to be publicly accessible. The naming convention for these (and the required naming convention when using the explicit `@property` keyword with `@synthesize` in Objective-C), is typically `setParameter` for the setter and `parameter` for the getter. Read about the properties [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Properties).

Comment: Yes, i do have acces to the "Fraction class example". Now i know what it means "Following the paradigm...". I read the link that you provide. I guess i'm not that far yet to grasp everything in that link, but i learned that there is new way for declaring variables in Objective-C 2.0 . Thank you for that too. I found an answer for similar exercis and after correcting my version i finally got it right. (i provided it as an "anwer" to this question). One of the thing that still not clear for me is usage of NSLog characters "%.2f+%.2fi" .

Comment: Since you are already acquainted with the task, would you mind explain it to me or send me a link where i can read about such usage?

Comment: Did i get it right: although we defined getter "real" and "imaginary" we actually didn't use them in our program ?

Comment: It's actually bad practice (and possibly a runtime error) to name your internal data members with the same name as the getter methods. The best practice is to use names like `_real` and `_imaginary` as the physical data member names, and in the methods `real` and `imaginary` return the values mentioned. [Here](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog) is a decent link describing the format characters used by NSLog. Note that the 'i' in `%.2f+%.2fi` is not part of the format string, but rather the letter `i` used to represent the imaginary unit `sqrt(-1)`.

Comment: And yes, you're correct, you don't actually use the getter methods in your program. Please mark my answer as correct if it satisfies your solution.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided doesn't have an explanation of usage ".2" with NSLog format specifiers.

Comment: My research says: usage of ".x" returns numbers with x digit after dot(decimals). Should be a separate article about that. So simple and no information about it.

Comment: Did i get it right: with getters we can't use NSLog function. To display results from getters we use "return". ?

Comment: The point of a getter is not to display the value to the log console; it's to use it in your program. For example, in `main` you might want to add `4 + 3i` to `num` as follows. First add 4 to the real part: `[num setReal:([num real] + 4)];` then add 3 to the imaginary part: `[num setImaginary:([num imaginary] + 3)];`

Comment: Thank you Marc for your help. I figured out that there is no way of sending private messages on stackoverflow. Would you mind being my mentor? All articles "How to learn to program" saying you have to have somebody who is a experienced programmer for an advice and help. Are you interested in equity? 3% of the company will be my gift to you :)

Answer (score 0):

After corrections, the answer is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Complex: NSObject
{
    double real, imaginary;
}

-(void)setReal: (double) a;

-(void)setImaginary: (double) b;

-(void) print;

-(double) real;

-(double) imaginary;

@end

@implementation Complex


-(void)setReal: (double) a
{
    real =a; 
}



-(void)setImaginary: (double) b

{
    imaginary = b;
}



-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"Your number is %.2f+%.2fi", real, imaginary);
}


-(double)real
{
    return real;
}



-(double)imaginary
{
    return imaginary;
}

@end



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

     NSAutoreleasePool*pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

Complex *myComplex=[[Complex alloc] init];

[myComplex setReal:3];
[myComplex setImaginary:4];
[myComplex print];

[myComplex release];
[pool drain];


    return 0;
}
```